# How do I use try and except to see if a file name I am entering is valid?

Tags: python

So the file is called 'data.txt'. I need to write a program that prompts the user for input to see if it matches 'data.txt'. So for example, if i enter 'data', it will output:

```
Enter name of file:
data
File data not found.
```

so far, when i input 'data', my code:

```
# Define your functions here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = "data.txt"

    # Prompt the user for the name of the file and try opening it for reading
    user_input = ''

    while user_input in ['data.txt']:
        try:
            user_input = input('Enter name of file:')
            my_file = open('data.txt')
            lines = my_file.read()

        # Use try-except to catch an error if the file does not exist
        except:
            print('File data not found.')
        # Complete main section of code to read the file, compute the average weight and height, etc.
```

However, this displays (Your program produced no output).

Any tips on how to debug my code? Or what I need to fix?

Comment: You can try filecmp
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1072576/3523510
Like write the content in file and then compare or see how it works behind the scene

Comment: add a print statement in try,i think there is nothing you are printing in try block

Comment: initially `user_input = ''` not in `['data.txt']` so your code never runned while loop and exit

Comment: I don't know if you specifically need to use try-except, but this may be worth a read: [How do I check whether a file exists without exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82831/2745495).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to open the file (and using a broad exception clause), you can check whether it exists with `os.path`.

```py
import os

def ask_file():
    while True:
        file = input("What is the file?")
        if os.path.exists(file):
             return file
        print("That file does not exist!")


ask_file()
```

Comment: thanks, though my assignment was specifically looking for a try-except clause. will note your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop was never executed because the condition is always false. You could try the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        user_input = input('Enter name of file: ')
        my_file = open(user_input)
        lines = my_file.read()

    except:
        print('File data not found.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
try:
    f = open('text.txt')
    f.close()
except:
    print('File not found.')
```